# How to split a patch in StGit?

Tags: git

I'm using [StGit](http://www.procode.org/stgit/) to manage my code using patches before I decide it's time to convert it to actual commits. *(sidenote: yes, I know, StGit patches are actually just commits under-the-hood)*

Then I added large amount of code to a single StGit patch, but now I want to split it into smaller patches (and later to smaller commits). How can I do that?

```
$ vim foobar.ext
Then I modify both functionA and functionB inside this file.
This might require changes in other files as well.
$ stg new large-patch
$ stg refresh
$ stg series
> large-patch

$ [insert here the answer to this question]

$ stg series
+ functionA-changes
> functionB-changes
$
```

Comment: This discussion (and solution) looks similar: https://www.mail-archive.com/stgit-users%40gna.org/msg00067.html

Answer (score 8):

There are several ways to do this. You can choose to break the patch itself in smaller peaces, or pick parts of it from the bottom or from the top.

Option 1: Split the patch itself:

```sh
$ stg delete large-patch --spill

### for each patch i in 0..N-1:
$ stg new sub-patch-$i
$ git add -p .
$ stg refresh --index
```

Option 2: Pick from its bottom:

```sh
$ stg pop large-patch

### for each patch i in 0..N-1:
$ stg new sub-patch-$i
$ git checkout -p $(stg id large-path)
$ stg refresh

$ stg push large-patch
```

Option 3: Pick from its top:

```sh
$ stg refresh
$ git reset HEAD~1 -p
$ stg refresh -i
$ stg new new-top-patch
$ stg refresh
```

This third option (from the top) is very handy, but it is a lot more complicated. You will be picking your changes in the reverse direction. When you are done with git reset, your changes in the index will be reverting those changes from the patch, while the changes in the working tree will be reverting the reverted changes, effectively creating a new patch with those changes.

Comment: stg delete --spill leaves the patch contents in the index. So I think you're missing a git reset here just after the stg delete.

Answer (score 4):

Remember just one command to make patch rearrangement safe: `std push --set-tree`. It pushes the next patch, but avoids the merge. Instead, it preserves the original file tree associated with the patch. In other words, the superposition of the patches is preserved even when individual patches are edited.

For splitting a patch, copy the original patch using `stg pick --unapplied`. After the original patch is edited, the copied patch would automatically pick up the changes removed from the original patch.

The whole process looks like this.

```
# Make sure the patch to be split is on top

# Copy the current patch
stg pick --unapplied $(stg top)

# Make the first patch: remove hunks that go to the
# second patch, edit the description
stg edit --diff

# Some changes may be on the finer level than hunks, so let's
# do the fine tuning, test the patch, and make sure to run
# this after editing:
stg refresh

# Done with the first patch, now we go to the second patch,
# --set-tree does all the magic
stg push --set-tree

# All that's left is to edit the description of the second patch
stg edit --diff
```

Comment: This is nice, thanks.  It would be great to get the upstream docs to include this example.

Comment: As I come back to this, I just wish I could upvote it some more!

Answer (score 2):

My solution so far:

```
$ stg pop
Popped large-patch
No patch applied

$ stg show large-patch | patch -p1

$ git add -p
Here I interactively select which portions are going to be staged.

$ stg new functionA-changes
$ stg refresh --index

$ stg new functionB-changes
$ stg refresh

$ stg push
Pushing patch "large-patch" ... done (empty)
Now at patch "large-patch"

$ stg delete large-patch
Deleted large-patch (empty)
Now at patch "functionB-changes"
```

There is an alternate approach:

```
$ stg pop
Popped large-patch
No patch applied

$ stg show large-patch > foobar.patch
$ vim foobar.patch
Manually edit the patch
$ patch -p1 < foobar.patch
Now the files only have the changes from functionA.

$ stg new functionA-changes
$ stg refresh

$ stg rename large-patch functionB-changes
$ stg push
Pushing patch "functionB-chages" ... done
Now at patch "functionB-chages"
```

It works, but is still a bit troublesome. I don't know if there is any better solution.